# Python code hangs during map function

Tags: python, mapreduce

This is what I am trying to do; write an Apriori in Python. The code is from a few years back and it has worked for me before. Was updating bits and pieces for it for Py3.0 and one of the first steps is to build a Candidate set.

The dataset looks like:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("editdf.csv", index_col= False)
df2.head()
```

[dataset example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1hsK.png)

I call this as:

```
Ap = apriori("editdf.csv",100)
print(Ap)
```

But there is no output; I have tried several debug options and hence it is littered with Print statements. The problem it seems is in the

```
num_list = map(int,input().split())
```

The overall piece of code is
The rogue code piece is:

```
def create_candidate_item_set(dataset_file):
    print ("Candidate Item stage")
    candidate_item_list = defaultdict(int)
    baskets = []
    counter =0
    print ("starting with")
    with open(dataset_file) as file:
        for line in file:
            print ("inside with")
            num_list = map(int,input().split())
            print ("this is", str(counter))
            baskets.append(num_list)
            counter +=1
            num_list
        for item in num_list:
            candidate_item_list[item] = 1 if item not in candidate_item_list else candidate_item_list[item]+1
    print ("got baskets")
    return candidate_item_list, baskets
```

I feel I am missing on something crucial but unable to put a finger on it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you giving some `stdin` data to the `input()` statement?

Comment: You are looping over the file line by line but not using any content apart from the number of lines for the counter; is that what you want?

Comment: @cdarke Its a standard dataset that has been massaged a bit; I have attached a pic of the same.

Comment: @Chris_Rands the counter is a debug exercise to see what and where stuff is getting stuck. So even if it just counts lines covered that's fine.

Comment: @Viks:  so how are you applying that to the `input()` statement?  It could well be "hanging" waiting for input from `stdin`.

Comment: @cdarke am not sure I understand the question I am calling in                   Ap = apriori("editdf.csv",100) then print(Ap) Is this what was asked?

Comment: @cdarke so the correct syntax is input(dataset_file).split? I have tried a few options all fail with error                                                                      " invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[' "

Comment: No!  `input()` is for reading from `stdin` - by default the console or keyboard.  Why are you using `input()`?  When your program hangs, just hit the <RETURN> key, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and I did the<RETURN> and realized what you meant. I thought input will naturally taken in whatever is associated at <WITH OPEN>. How do I redirect it to take input from the file dataset_file? Don't mean to tax your patience so please share a link if an explanation is too long. Thanks -@cdarke

Comment: @cdrake sorted it... Thanks !!! Not sure how I can upvote this answer cause....

Answer (score 1):

In python 3, you need to explicitly convert to a list when mapping.  So

```
num_list = list(map(int,input().split()))
```

Should do it.

Comment: Did the above. This hasn't helped. I still do not have any output from line. The iPython kernel is still busy for last 5 mins and I feel it has hanged.